# What is Nix equivalent of "guix challenge"?

Tags: nixos, nix, guix, guixsd

In Guix user can verify reproducibility of a package with `guix challenge` https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Invoking-guix-challenge.html.

What is the Nix command for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `nix-build` you can use `--check --keep-failed`.

The minimal NixOS reproducibility is being tracked here: https://r13y.com/. You might look at the instructions there how to use it with diffoscope.